# Is exists a way to commit several directories not in a tree structure in only one master branch on git?

Tags: git, debian, debian-buster

What I'm trying to do is git in a one master branch the following structure:

```
/var/www/mysite/public_html
/dev/only_this_file.txt
/etc/directory/things
/other/other/other/other
```

and everything without generating any git file inside any of those directories or subdirectories, that must be untouched.

Is this possible?

I'm working on Debian Buster

Comment: Sounds like you need a repo with an installation procedure that deploys from within your sandbox to those locations. Short answer is no, because a Git repo starts with a root directory.

Comment: @joanis The only workaround I can think is do some kind of resync or cp to a root directory and then commit that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. To make your life easier, script that resync operation so you can just run it whenever needed, rather than having to remember what's what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a working directory with the use of `--git-dir` and `--work-dir` (or the corresponding environment variables `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`)

e.g.

```sh
cd /var/www/mysite/public_html
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$(pwd)
git --git-dir=/home/git/mysite init
git --git-dir=/home/git/mysite add *
git --git-dir=/home/git/mysite commit
```

(you would probably want to define an alias that sets the proper arguments)

i don't think you can have multiple disjoint working-trees living in the same git repository.

Comment: I don't quite understand this solution. I see it lets you separate where the git repo's .git directory is from where the files are, but doesn't this still need a root directory? I looks to me like it will still only include files under `public_html` with your example commands.